# Nginx setup on aws - redirecting to port 81, cannot reverse

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I've tried to setup nginx on my free AWS instance so that it can host multiple domains on single ip address (not sure if it can be managed, but I'm trying to dig in). In that process I created dancemilkdance.com file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and also there is default file. Default was on listen 81 and dancemilkdance.com on listen 80, was playing around try to see what will happen, and now they are both on listen 80 (dancemilkdance.com have default_server now), BUT it keeps redirecting me to the port 81.

After each change I restart service, also I'm using `sudo nginx -t` to check if everything is proper. I will put nginx configuration here so that you can see it.

note 1) I would like not to delete default file, but to manage to really find what is the root of this problem

note 2) If you have a solution that will work for multiple domains that would be great

note 3) Even a hint is enough

dancemilkdance.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name dancemilkdance.com   www.dancemilkdance.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dancemilkdance.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dancemilkdance.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/dancemilkdance.com/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include common/php.conf;

    include common/wpcommon.conf;
    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/dancemilkdance.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

My domain is (you've guessed it) dancemilkdance.com

EDIT 1) I've removed default, and restarted instance, still same solution. Site is displayed properly only if I put on port 81, but then site go empty on default www.dancemilkdance.com (:80)

EDIT 2) I reinstalled nxing, did everything from scratch, and it's working now. Phase 2 would be to create another domain on same ip/insance

Comment: you need to place that dancemilkdance.com configuration file in /sites-enabled/ folder in nginx. and then reload the server.

Comment: When I restart service, it automatically transfer to the /sites-enabled, along with default

Comment: Can you tell me how many files are there inside sites-enabled/

Comment: 2 of them 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 May 15 09:40 dancemilkdance.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/dancemilkdance.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 May 15 09:00 default1 -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default'